# put contents of array into string with new line php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file that contains strings that are on new lines like so:

```
string1
string2
```

I want to remove duplicates so i add them to an array, do unique so removes duplicates and now im trying to remove the array and put the contents into a string putting back the line breaks ("\n").

Code is below:

```
$input = file_get_contents('/srv/test.m3u');
$input = explode("\n", $input);

$result = array_unique($input);

foreach($result as $value){
    $newresult .= $value;
}

echo($newresult); //Comes back everything stuck together no line-breaks etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the implode function.

```
$input = file_get_contents('/srv/test.m3u');
$input = explode("\n", $input);

$result = array_unique($input);

$newresult = implode("\n",$result);

echo($newresult);
```

Answer (score 1):

use implode to add the "\n" like this:

```
$input = file_get_contents('/srv/test.m3u');
$input = explode("\n", $input);

$result = array_unique($input);
echo implode("\n", $result);
```